# How to set context before render in Next.js with app router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The way my app is organized is it's wrapped in an AuthContext that is holding a loggedIn state. I have a useEffect hook in my context provider, so that whenever the context provider is initially mounted, it validates whether the existing refreshToken is valid via a request to backend.

When the app is rendered for the first time, it initially appears as if the user was logged off and the appearance updates only after the context is being updated, which is not a big deal, but it looks bad with the menus and navigation bar switching the states.

I tried conditional rendering, but it's bad for SEO, since the search engine takes the temporary loading component as a proper response for any URL, since it's what is always displayed first before the context is set.

What can I do to prevent rendering the app before the context is set?

Comment: DId you try using a class component and doing the validation in constructor? Better for SEO as well I guess.
Or you could try doing it in the body instead of a useEffect, and mount the children after you have the result - because what you want is to render once and not render and update.

Comment: You could move the primary portion of the app into another component, use `useContext` to access the user state, and conditionally render the application based on that, using a spinner or something of the sorts while fetching data.